# Deleting values in Hbase-Hive Integration

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I am using Hbase for data storage and I have Hive table to read data from Hbase using Storage Handler.

I am Using a `Composite ROWKEY` `(Struct (region,country,date,id))`.

Is there any way to delete specific data from Hbase-Hive Integaration ,either from Hbase or from HIve??

Can something like below be done using HBase shell commands or Hive queries

```
delete from table where region=EU and country=US and date=2015-06-11;
```

using Hive 0.14

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Other than the fact that you need to quote the string values in the HiveQL, have you tried running that query in Hive?

Comment: As @cricket_007 mentioned,   As of Hive version 0.14.0: INSERT...VALUES, UPDATE, and DELETE are now available with full ACID support. suggested readings for you https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions  and https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML

Comment: Thanks guys .but I am looking for delete operation in Hbase-Hive Integrated model(External Hive table ove Hbase data via HbaseStorageHandler). I completely agree Hive 0.14 has update and delete ,but with ORC table formats.In Hbase-Hive Integration model that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions#HiveTransactions-Limitations

> Tables must be bucketed to make use of these features.  Tables in the same system not using transactions and ACID do not need to be bucketed. External tables cannot be made ACID tables since the changes on external tables are beyond the control of the compactor (HIVE-13175).

So apparently there is no way to perform delete in HBase using Hive.